# How do I manage permissions in firefox and chrome using selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, permissions, user-profile

How do I manage permissions in firefox and chrome using selenium? I am having problem to handle this situation in selenium.

Comment: Extremely unclear. What do you mean by permission? Authentication?

Comment: This problem comes when "Set Location"  appears in firefox  with the dispaly of google map

Answer (score 1):

Create custom profiles and use, instead of default profiles

Comment: This is possible by custom profile but we can't deliver  with custom profile to client.Client can  execute script and will not except to add custom profile every time.